# Strange error when serializing to JSON an array of objects which have a toJSON method

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, nswag

I use a NSwag to generate TypeScript typings and classes for swagger API endpoints. The resulting classes contain a `.toJSON()` method for each object which gets called when serializing objects to JSON using `JSON.stringify()`.

All works fine when serializing a single object, but when I try to serialize an Array of objects it throws a weird error:

```
angular.js:14199 TypeError: Cannot create property 'code' on string '0'
    at Dashboard.toJSON (App/models/api.js:785:34)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

and the code that triggers it is pretty simple:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([
        Dashboard.fromJS({
            code: "1212312",
            name: "tresads",
            description: "some description"
        }),
        Dashboard.fromJS({
            code: "1212312",
            name: "tresads",
            description: "some description"
        })
    ]));
```

An excerpt of the class:

```
export class Dashboard implements IDashboard {
    code?: string | undefined;
    ...

    constructor(data?: IDashboard) {
        if (data) {
            for (var property in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(property))
                    (<any>this)[property] = (<any>data)[property];
            }
        }
    }

    init(data?: any) {
        if (data) {
            this.code = data["code"];
            ...
        }
    }

    static fromJS(data: any): Dashboard {
        let result = new Dashboard();
        result.init(data);
        return result;
    }

    toJSON(data?: any) {
        data = data ? data : {};
        data["code"] = this.code;
        ...
        return data; 
    }

    clone() {
        const json = this.toJSON();
        let result = new Dashboard();
        result.init(json);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Any idea why `JSON.stringify()` calls the `toJSON()` method with the "0" parameter?

Comment: Maybe because the first index of the passed array is 0?

Comment: It certainly looks so. But why does it pass the index of the element to the `toJSON` method as a parameter?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output of the `console.log(JSON.stringify([...`, so I can provide a more to-the-point answer?

Comment: [
       {            "code": "1212312",
            "name": "tresads",
            "description": "some description"
        },
        {
            "code": "1212312",
            "name": "tresads",
            "description": "some description"
        }
    ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `toJSON` will be called with one argument, which is the property name to which `this` is assigned. In essence, the value of your interest is not that argument, but `this`, which will be bound to the value that you could transform. Since you call `stringify` with an array, `toJSON` will get called with the enumerable properties of that array, i.e. `0` and `1`, while `this` will be the corresponding Dashboard object.

Also, I have the impression you could make good use of `Object.assign` which will copy properties from one object to another, which is essentially what you do in the constructor's `for` loop.

So here is how you could do it. I removed the typescript decoration and used plain JavaScript, but the principle remains the same:

```js
class Dashboard {
    constructor(data) {
        // Object.assign does essentially what you want with the loop:
        Object.assign(this, data); 
    }

    init(data) {
        return Object.assign(this, data); 
    }

    static fromJS(data) {
        return new Dashboard(data);
    }

    toJSON(key) { 
        // `key` is the key/index of the property in the parent object.
        //    That probably is of no interest to you. You need `this`.
        // Extract properties into plain object, and return it for stringification
        return Object.assign({}, this);
    }

    clone() {
        return new Dashboard(this);
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify([
        Dashboard.fromJS({
            code: "1212312",
            name: "tresads",
            description: "some description"
        }),
        Dashboard.fromJS({
            code: "1212312",
            name: "tresads",
            description: "some description"
        })
    ]));
```

Actually, in the given example, you don't need `toJSON` at all, since the properties of the Dashboard instance are enumerable, and so they will be stringified anyway. If for some reason you do need it for a certain transformation to happen, then of course you still need to include the logic for that transformation, since `Object.assign` is just a simple copy.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation :)

Comment: I would love to know where you found out that "The method toJSON will be called with one argument, which is the property name to which this is assigned." as I have been searching for hours and this has been the first mention of it I could find?

Comment: @duckworth, [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) and [EcmaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-serializejsonproperty).